# Angular 9 migration with internal library using Ivy

Tags: angular, upgrade, ivy

I hope you are doing well in those weird times !

I just upgraded both of my internal library and its consumming applications to angular 9.
Since this library is designed by myself I havn't desabled Ivy.

The packaging of the library works fine, and when using `ng serve` for developping purpose it works fine as well.

But when building the app using `ng build --prod`, or serving it using `ng serve my-lib --prod` I get the following error in some part of the application :

```
Error: "The pipe 'async' could not be found!"
```

The application is using lazy loaded module and the CommonModule is properly imported everywhere it's needed (through the `SharedModule`)

It seems to be something related with Ivy enable inside my library, so I tried to desabled it but then when running the consumming application (even with `ng serve`), I get the following error :

```
ERROR in ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/workspace/my-library/dist/my-library/fesm2015/query-result-table.component.html'
```

Yet this html seems to be included in the .js.map file.

I have no idea on how I can fix this, if anyone has already encountered this king of issue I would appreciate any help !

Thanks

Comment: As per angular docs , if you are library author you should be publishing the lib with enableIvy: 'false' in angularCompilerOptions in your tsconfig.lib.json.
Can you add more details related to error after disabling IVY or repo for local setup.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Indeed libraries should not enable Ivy but this is an internal librarie used by internal application for whom Ivy is enabled !
I finally found the issue, it was an import of a component that was breaking everything (don't know yet why) !